# Print report in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to print report absent with range example date May 1, 2014 until date May 10, 2014 but link onclick its not working. result link like this

```
http://localhost/tkd/index.php/pelatih/cetak/cetak_absensi//
```

view

```
<a class="ui red small labeled button" href="#" onclick="document.location='<?php echo(site_url('pelatih/cetak/cetak_absensi'));?>'+'/'+document.getElementById('datepicker').value+'/'+document.getElementById('datepicker2').value; return false;">Cetak</a>
```

and my controller like this

```
function cetak_absensi()
    {
        $tgl_awal = $this->uri->segment(4);
        $tgl_akhir = $this->uri->segment(5);
        $this->data['absensi'] = $this->mabsensi->get_absensi_by_tanggal($tgl_awal, $tgl_akhir);
        $this->data['title'] ='UKM Taekwondo | laporan';

        $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
        $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('pelatih/cetak/cetak_absensi', $this->data, true);
        $this->load->view('template/wrapper/wrapper_cetak',$this->data);
    }
```

Before I print I must search data. And search data is working but when I print data inside report not display.

Please help me, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You made link very complex. Better to get value [`$_GET` or `$_POST`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) ,

if you use  get method , will have params like

```
$datepicker1 = $_GET['datepicker1'];
$datepicker2 = $_GET['datepicker2'];
```

Your link,

```
<a href="<?php echo(site_url('pelatih/cetak/cetak_absensi'));?>">Cetak</a>
```

Controller,

```
function cetak_absensi()
{
    $tgl_awal = $this->uri->segment(4) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : $_GET['datepicker1'];
    $tgl_akhir = $this->uri->segment(5) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : $_GET['datepicker2'];
    $this->data['absensi'] = $this->mabsensi->get_absensi_by_tanggal($tgl_awal, $tgl_akhir);
    $this->data['title'] ='UKM Taekwondo | laporan';

    $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('pelatih/cetak/cetak_absensi', $this->data, true);
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/wrapper_cetak',$this->data);
}
```